# Having trouble importing my csv data into a table using D3

Tags: d3.js

Apologies if this is rudimentary but I am new to D3. I'm having trouble importing my csv data and displaying it as a table that can be opened in a browser. All my data files and code are located in the same folder. Here is the code I have so far and my csv data. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**SublimeFile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 2px grey solid;
                font: 12px sans-serif;
            }

            td {
                border: 1px grey solid;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            body {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            margin-left:40px;
            font-weight: 200;
            font-size: 16px;
            }

            h1 {font-weight: 400;}

            p {font-size: 12px;}

            text {font-size: 12px;}
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "Chart"></div>
        <script>
            d3.text("dashboard.csv", function(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.csv**

```
Entity,Entity A
Head of Data,Albert Aldridge
DG Lead,Anna Annovo
BIO,April Autumn
Business Participants,"Alfred, Adeline, Amy"
Scope,European Platforms
Scope Trend,Steady
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me (with your csv), if you are unable to get the code to work, how are you testing it?

Comment: Perhaps you are not using a web server in order to execute the page. If it is the case you could be having the error "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.". You can use a lightweight web server like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts, I was able to figure it out. I was trying to run the .html file in chrome & internet explorer with no luck. It seems to only work in firefox for me.